# WebDAV - Mini-Redirector - delete file/directory - failed response

Tags: webdav, ithit-webdav-server

I use your IT Hit WebDAV server and I try to send 'failed' response on delete request to Mini-Redirector (Microsoft WebDAV client). I checked all available 'failed response' (401, 402, 423) and I see that Mini-Redirector ignores it (file/directory is deleted and restored on refresh).

Do you know how it should be handled to prevent delete file/directory on Mini-Redirector side?

Answer (score 0):

As far as we know Mini-Redirector's reaction to response codes is undocumented. From our experience it just ignores any response codes.

Comment: Thank you for your response and confirmation that Mini-Redirector just ignores any response codes.

I applied the following workaround to prevent deleting folders: set read-only attribute for selected folders. I see that it prevents deleting these folders via Microsoft WebDAV client (message: Folder Access Denied).